# Error in a math expression

Tags: math-mode, errors

I have a problem with this expression:

```
$$n \geq \Bigg\lvert \bigcup_{l \leq |A_{i}| \leq 2l} |A_{i}| \Bigg\rvert \geq \sum_{i = 1}^{N_{l}}\Bigg\lvert A_{i} \Biggl \bigcup_{j =1}^{i-1} A_{j}\Biggr \Bigg\rvert$$
```

The report is:

> `* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
>   * ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\bblopts.cfg") ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\italian.ldf"
>   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")))
>   (C:\Users\Stefano1\Desktop\Seminario\Seminario.aux) ("C:\Program
>   Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd") ("C:\Program
>   Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd") ("C:\Program
>   Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omscmr.fd") [1{C:/ProgramData/MiKT
>   eX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] !
>   Missing delimiter (. inserted).  
>                      \bigcup@  l.296 ...}^{N_{l}}\Bigg\lvert A_{i} \Biggl \bigcup
>                                                     *{j =1}^{i-1} A*{j}\Biggr ...
>
> ? `

I don't understand where is the error.

Comment: Don't use `$$`. This is outdated. Use one $ for inline or `\[ \]` for display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both after one `\Biggl` and one `\Biggr` a delimiter, such as `\lvert` or `\rvert` or any other (parenthessis, brace, dot), is missing. There's just a blank and another command following.

Compilable example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
  n \geq \Bigg\lvert \bigcup_{l \leq |A_{i}| \leq 2l} |A_{i}|
  \Bigg\rvert \geq \sum_{i = 1}^{N_{l}}\Bigg\lvert A_{i} \Biggl\lvert
  \bigcup_{j =1}^{i-1} A_{j}\Biggr\rvert \Bigg\rvert
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: As you just write, it would be great to have all `\Bigg` changed to `\Biggl \Biggr` and so on.

Comment: I think the expression would look even better if you replaced all `\Bigg` directives with `\bigg`: Just as it's not desirable in general, to surround a summation sign with upper and lower limits with parentheses that fully enclose the entire expression, the vertical bars generated by `\Bigg` seem oppresively tall; switching to `\bigg[lr]` will give less visual prominence to the fences, without creating any uncertainty as to what's being enclosed.